# Browser based WebDAV client?

Tags: browser, webdav

Is there any good browser based WebDAV client? If not, is it possible to make one?

Comment: I can answer your second question. Yes, it is possible.There is nothing software can't do. Except may be making coffee, but I am sure, someone is already working on it. ;)

Comment: it can make coffee: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Coffee.html

Comment: Even coffe shouldn't be a problem if you have a HTCPCP-enabled coffemachine, as described in RFC2324.

Comment: codefx, what do you mean by "browser based"? Should it run as a plugin to the web browser?

Comment: I mean without installing any browser plugin on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you expect the client to do, and whether you're looking for a cross-browser "web application", or a browser extension.

The main issue with doing this in a "web application" (as opposed to a browser extension) is (1) the lack of binary data support in Javascript, and (2) the lack of access to the local file system (which of course is a security feature).

Comment: Firefox 3.5, Chrome 4 and Safari 4 now provide access to local file system. You can upload files files using pure JavaScript/XHR via PUT as WebDAV specification requires. We have implemented this support in IT Hit Ajax File Browser. Unfortunately IE still does not support upload via PUT, hope they will fix this in IE 9. 

Moreover, implementations or CORS in Firefox, Safati and Chrome allow cross-domain access to WebDAV servers.

Comment: Update to my above comment, since IE 9 and IE 10 were released: IE 10 supports WebDAV upload via PUT verb. IE 9 does not support PUT upload. So now you can build a fully-functional WebDAV client that runs in IE 10, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: No Julian, IE 9 and earlier can upload files only via form submission. That is using POST request. Upload via PUT became possible only when File API was introduced in IE 10.

Comment: PUT has been supported for ages. What's new is the file API, not support for PUT.

Comment: We now also have support for binary handling with `Uint8Array` and family.

Comment: "the lack of binary data support in Javascript," what? The `ArrayBuffer` infrastructure exists just for that.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't shipping when that answer was written.

Answer (score 9):

Look at the AjaxFileBrowser from [ITHit](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser).  Pretty slick, and has FireFox & Chrome PUT support for uploading.  IE, drag-and-drop from your desktop to the browser.  They have a fully functional demo site up at http://www.ajaxbrowser.com.

Comment: Well, without hashing the benefits of open-source software, they did put a lot of time & effort into it and should be compensated.  Alternatively, it's 100% pure JavaScript.... not sure how they'd enforce any type of DRM ...

Comment: Gonna split a hair and correctyou - *free software. Open source is not necessarily free of either price nor legal encumberments.

Answer (score 7):

There's a [plugin for Firefox](http://webfolder.mozdev.org/index.html) which handles WebDAV.

> Webfolders is a firefox extension that gives you the ability to view the contents of WebDAV
>   servers in the browser and use the full functionality of the WebDAV protocol.

Comment: Checked in 2020, the plugin 'Webfolders' is not available in the list of extensions anymore > https://addons.mozilla.org

Comment: The plugin is still available for Thunderbird but it useless: it just creates ActiveX Object with Explorer and this won't work anymore in Windows.
I created my own extension based on webdav-js https://github.com/stokito/webdav-browser-extension

Comment: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/open-as-webfolder/

Answer (score 3):

There is [webdav-js](https://github.com/dom111/webdav-js) which can be used as a [browser extension](https://github.com/stokito/webdav-browser-extension), as a bookmarklet or served by the WebDAV server itself as an HTML page.

It supports the regular listing of files and directories, file upload, directory creation, renaming, as well as in-page display of images and other media.

Comment: As of end of 2022, it does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If by browser based you mean that it runs in html (ie you don't want your users to install a plugin) then the answer is *partly yes* and *mostly no.*

Partly yes, because I have built and used one. It uses the jquery jtree plugin to display folders, and selecting a folder node populates a file list in the right hand panel. Panels are done with another jquery plugin, and the file list is made dynamic with the jquery datatables plugin.

But I think for you the answer is probably "no". Thats because for the browser to use webdav is must user webdav "methods" like PROPFIND and MKCOL. These methods just arent supported in most browsers, so your javascript can't use them directly. I have a server-side mapping in my webdav server project which allows my javascript to use normal GET and POST methods, and these requests are transformed on the server to webdav methods.

I said "probably no" for you since this serve side mapping isnt standard, its a part of milton. But if you happen to use milton, or you can use milton, then its all good.

Comment: This reply is outdated; modern browsers *do* allow JavaScript applications to send PROPFIND and MKCOL requests.

Comment: And have done so back then years ago as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try SMEStorage.com. They turn any WebDav back-end into a personal cloud file solution. As well as a rich browser desktop and mobile client, there are clients for Mac,Windows, Linux and Mobile clients for Android, iOS, Windows Phone, and BlackBerry.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly from a browser but there is a nice Chrome App [File Management - WebDav](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/file-management-webdav/famepaffkmmhdefbapbadnniioekdppm). It's not fully translated from Chinese   so here is hint: Press `Add+` and in Service Provider select the last item `自定义` e.g. configure a custom WebDAV server. Everything else should be clear